# Typescript type mismatch

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For some reason i keep getting error even when the types seem correctly to me:

```
    //* ListWithCards has base of List but contains {cards: Card[]} field
    //* ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues has base of List but the card type is {cards: CardWithCustomFieldValue[]}

    export const recover = (tApi: TrelloRestApi, reportError: CreateErrorReport) => (withException: boolean) => async <
      P extends List | ListWithCards | ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues | string,
      T = P extends string ? List : Exclude<P, 'string'>
    >(
      param: P
    ): Promise<T> => {
      //* tApi.get.list takes string as an argument and returns List type
      //* isString is a typeguard that checks if passed param is string
      //* List results in:  List | P
      const list = isString(param) ? await tApi.get.list(param) : param;
      try {
        if ('closed' in list && list.closed) {
          await tApi.update.list(list.id, { closed: false });
          if (withException) await reportError(eTools.listRecovererErrorCard(list));
        }

        //* error: Spread types may only be created from object types
        return { ...list, closed: false };
      } catch (error) {
        await reportError(error);
        //* error: Type 'List | P' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        // * Type 'List' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        //* 'List' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'List | ListWithCards | ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues'
        return list;
      }
    };
```

I would expect that after checking if `param` is a string list would end up being: `List | ListWithCards | ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues` but instead when spreading it complains that `list` is not an object which is an object at that point, or at least it should be seen as such.

here is also code sample from stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yyaj4u?file=index.ts

Note that i'm using version of typescript 3.7.2 in my project but the error still appears even on stackblitz which has pretty sure different version.

Comment: can you post complete code, so that it is easier to debug. Or better provide stackblitz.

Comment: done, edited with link to stackblitz

Comment: What should be desired return type? `T`or `P` ?

Comment: It would be T, if the passed parameter is a string the returning type should be a List. While when it's not a string returning type should be based on the P type

Answer (score 0):

There are some conflicts here.

1. You have return variable `list` which has type `P | List`
2. `T` is subtype of `P`, `T extends P extends string ? List : Exclude<P, "string">`
3. Your return type is `T`.

So, you can not return type `P | List` by this declaration as `T` is subtype of `P`. I think you should omit `T` altogether.

```js
export const listRecoverer = (
  tApi: TrelloRestApi,
  reportError: (error: Error) => Promise<void>
) => (withException: boolean) => async <
  P extends List | ListWithCards | ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues | string
>(
  param: P
): Promise<P | List> => {
  const list = isString(param) ? await tApi.get.list(param) : param;

  try {
    if ("closed" in list && list.closed) {
      await tApi.update.list(list.id, { closed: false });
      if (withException) await reportError(new Error(""));
    }

    return { ...list, closed: false };
  } catch (error) {
    await reportError(error);

    // P extends string | List | ListWithCards | ListWithCardsWithCustomFieldValues
    // T extends P extends string ? List : Exclude<P, "string">
    // const list: P | List

    return list;
  }
};
```

Comment: The only problem is i would never return string while the function return type does indicate that possibility due to P. Also when trying this solution i'm getting the same issue when spreading the list which complains about "Spread types may only be created from object types"

Also checked it on stack blitz and there the spread error doesn't happen, i guess it's typescript version difference?

Comment: Are you seeing the error in stackblitz? Bcoz i dont have any error thr

Comment: seems like it doesn't show up on stackblitz but does in my code https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/12/8/8ab128ccc5831b2748096adf930aae5b-full.png

Comment: I dont understand need of `...list`? there is only one list,  and you are not doing any operation on it

Comment: i spread it as i want to ensure "closed" field is always false, when returning it inside catch i don't do it because i cannot ensure that.

Also about the error on the screenshot downgrading to typescript 3.6.3 solves it  but on versions 3.7.2+ it's broken